# Questions about Automatic variables in makefile

Tags: makefile

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

I don't understand the difference between $? and $^. The document says $? returns the names of all prerequisites that are newer than the target whereas $^ returns all prerequisites.

However, I tried to test it with many examples and none of them worked?  Could anyone provide me an example?

Also: What are order-only prerequisites? I don't understand what 'order-only' means. This is from the following definition:

$| :
The names of all the order-only prerequisites, with spaces between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show us an example that you tried that didn't work, we can be more help.  Here's a simple example:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: foo bar
        @echo '$$? = $?'
        @echo '$$^ = $^'

$ touch foo; sleep 1; touch all; sleep 1; touch bar

$ make
$? = bar
$^ = foo bar
```

You can find information on [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) in the GNU make manual.

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly demonstrates the difference